# UI Bootstrap Accordion content not showing on click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I'm trying to add an accordion element, but clicking on one accordion header results in nothing (in my application I can actually see the content transition in and then transition out, as if it encountered some condition instructing it to collapse).

I've managed to extract the behaviour in the following codepen:
https://codepen.io/deepdown22/pen/LYNQYeb

```
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
      <p>Start editing and see your changes reflected here!</p>
    
      {{groups}}

      
    <uib-accordion close-others="true">
    
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="group.open">
      <uib-accordion-heading>
        {{group.title}}
      </uib-accordion-heading>
      {{group.content}}
    </div>
    
  </uib-accordion>
    </div>
  </div>

angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('plunker').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Plunker';
  $scope.groups = [
    {'title': 'a', 'content': 'b'}, 
    {'title': 'c', 'content': 'd'}
   ];
});
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't put my finger on what.

Answer (score 1):

1. First check out the documentation for uib-accordion (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). You are using it wrong.
   Not `<div uib-accordion>` it is `<uib-accordion>`
2. Codepen is useless without the css

Comment: 1. I haven't used it as <div uib-accordion>, but as <uib-accordion>. Neither of them works. 2. Why do you say it's useless without css? For a small example, I didn't consider it necessary to add more styling.

Comment: Ok check that the versions of bootstrap.css, ui-bootstrap.js and angular.js are compatible with each other. Check out https://morgul.github.io/ui-bootstrap4/ You also need ngAnimate and ngTouch

Comment: That was it. The library was incompatible with the Bootstrap version I was using (4). Thanks for the lib recommendation, it looks promising!

Comment: Good. Please accept my answer as the correct answer if it works ;)